# linux kernel module permissions

Tags: c, linux, permissions, module, kernel

I wrote a kernel module and a user that opens it with O_RDWR mode,

in the module_permission's func i get int op parameter ,

and would like to know if its value is the same as O_RDWR or maybe the system call open changes it to another known value , and if so where can i find it..

thanks a lot..

Comment: Do you mean you wrote a character device driver, and the user opens the character device with O_RDWR? You probably have just forgotten to set up read and write operations for it in your module. Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean your module exports a device node that the user opens as a file with O_RDWR? In this case if you are using a newer kernel, the mode is in the struct file* parameter passed to your module's open call:

```
int my_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* filep) 
{
    unsigned mode = file->f_mode;
    //... 
}
```